# minimum honoring others

Tags: halacha, middos-character-traits, bein-adam-lachavero, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef

chazal tell us 24,000 students of Rabbi Akiva were wiped out in a plague due to not giving honor to each other. (Yevamot 62b)

אמרו שנים עשר אלף זוגים תלמידים היו לו לרבי עקיבא מגבת עד אנטיפרס וכולן מתו בפרק אחד מפני שלא נהגו כבוד זה לזה

is there any kind of guidance as to what is the minimum amount of honor that one should grant to others according to halacha to fulfill one's obligation in this?

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53776/759

Comment: @DoubleAA not asking about loving others. just treating them with respect

Comment: see [this shiur](http://olamot.net/shiur/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%92%D7%95-%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%96%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%96%D7%94) which maintains that according to the Maharal and the Meharsha the students did not respect **the Torah** of the others "לא חש כל אחד מהם על כבוד התורה של חברו".

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok thanks. maybe should leave out that point as it may confuse the question

Comment: @ray I meant to challenge your question. Can you find a source that shows that the "honor" was other than respect for the Torah of others?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok that is the plain meaning